# API for parsing network capture (.cap) file

Tags: c#, .net, api

I have a network capture file (`.cap`). Is there an API that allows me to manipulate it from C#?

Comment: You can use SharpPcap ` http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12458/SharpPcap-A-Packet-Capture-Framework-for-NET